# What's that "MainActivity.this is not enclosing class" error actually?

Tags: java, android

I'm having problem in executing the following code.

Actually I wanted to use an image as a link to another page or activity. How it's done

and

what's that "MainActivity.this is not enclosing class" problem actually?
Here is a code

I have 2 classes, 1st is MainActivity

and

2nd is MainActivity2

both are in Single MainAcitvity.java file

MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton androidImageButton;
        @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });





        androidImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_android);
        androidImageButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            });



    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MainActivity2:

```
class MainActivity2 extends MainActivity implements OnClickListener, View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton Btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageButton Btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_android);
    Btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.i("clicks","You Clicked B1");
    Intent i;
    i = new Intent( MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class); *//The problem is here wih MainActivity.this//
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Can any one please resolve the error and help me out with the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An **enclosing class** is exactly what it sounds like - it's a class that *encloses* (not inherits) the class at the given statement. In order to reference the enclosing class instance, the **this** keyword must be prefixed with the class name - hence `MainActivity.this`.

```
class ABC {
    class XYZ extends Activity {
    } 
}
```

In the simple example above, `ABC` is the *enclosing* class of `XYZ`.

Your error is telling you that `MainActivity` is not an enclosing class at the statement location, and so the `this` instance of that class cannot be accessed.

Your `MainActivity2` class *inherits* from `MainActivity`, but there is no  *enclosing* class at the `Intent(...)` statement. Since the `Intent()` constructor requires a `Context` parameter and your `MainActivity2` `this` instance inherits from `Context` (Context -> Activity -> MainActivity -> MainActivity2), you can just use `this` as the parameter:

So instead of:

```
 i = new Intent( MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
```

use:

```
 i = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
```

Comment: I truly appreciate your reply thanks alot for that.
According to your guide line I combined both of the classes. 
As far as I got this 'enclosing' means to combine these classes as 1.
Am I right?

Comment: Enclosing is not telling you to combine the classes or do anything different - the word simply describes one class that sits inside of another. The error you are getting is because you are trying to access MainActivity as an enclosing class when it's not.

Comment: @adelphus Thanks dear. You solution worked for me .. by the way i have used ( new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Mainactivity.class)) and this is also working for me.

Comment: thankyou, you solve my problem which i try to solve on this last 12 hours.